# Why is the exception bubbling all the way up here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In short, my problem is that I'm trying to return a file through a controller, but sometimes the file is locked by another process, causing my controller to return `null`.

My controller was like (This isn't the exact, but it's equivalent)

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetFile(int fileid)
{
   string filepath = GetFilePathFromId(fileid); 
   return new FileDownload(filepath);
}

public class FileDownload : IHttpActionResult
{
     private string FilePath { get; set; }
     public FileDownload(string filePath)
     {
         FilePath = filepath;
     }
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open))
        };

        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath)
        };

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

and this was sometimes returning a generic XML 
error

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message></Error>
```

When I looked in Event Viewer, I saw that there was an exception thrown

> The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by
>   another process.

I know why this is, and as a quick solution I did

```
        IHttpActionResult file = null;
        var fiveSecondsLater = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
        while(DateTime.Now < fiveSecondsLater)
        {
            try
            {
                file = new FileDownload(filepath);
                break;
            }
            catch 
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
        return file ?? Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Could not access file.");
```

However, strangely enough, this was still causing the XML error! Very strange since I'm catching the exception and not re-throwing it. Any idea what the flaw is here and how I can fix it?

EDIT:

Stack trace points to line

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

as the problem one. Stack trace is like

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at ....FileDownload.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ...:line 81
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: That XML response looks pretty generic.  Maybe a different exception is causing it?  What's the exact exception this time and which line throws it?

Comment: @David It's the same one. I'm gonna post the stack trace above.

Comment: Can you ensure the caller does not timeout while calling GetFile and maybe also ensure file does not get locked again until the download starts?

Comment: `file = new FileDownload(filepath)` probably always succeeds first time. I don't have source to hand but a well-written constructor never does 'work'. You need to actually force access to the file to check that you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the quick fix to retry the open file operation sometimes later I recommend to search for the root cause why the file is locked by a process.

It is worth a try to alter the `FileStream` creation logic not to open the stream exclusively. The following slightly extended creation logic reduces the risk of file locks.

```
Content = new StreamContent(
             new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```